# rails group by and order by column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my controller I'm getting all Extras grouped by Category:

```
def index
  @categories = Extra.all.group_by(&:category)
end
```

The result is something like an Array of Hashes:

```
{#<Category id:1, sort:2> => [#<Extra id:1>,#<Extra id:2],
 #<Category id:2, sort: 1> => [#<Extra id:3>,#<Extra id:4>]}
```

I want to sort by category "sort" column instead of id, which should look like this:

```
{#<Category id:2, sort:1> => [#<Extra id:3>,#<Extra id:4],
 #<Category id:1, sort: 2> => [#<Extra id:1>,#<Extra id:2>]}
```

When I try:

```
def index
  @categories = Extra.all.group_by(&:category).sort_by{|s| s[:sort]}
end
```

I get "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer". Is that because I used a symbol in the "sort_by"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this, `group_by` will return you `hash` and you are trying to call `[:sort]` on an Array of `[#<Category id:2, sort:1>, [#<Extra id:3>,#<Extra id:4]]`

You should take them in two variables `|key, value|` and the key will be `category`

```
def index
  @categories = Extra.all.group_by(&:category).sort_by{|category, _extras| category.sort }
end
```

Comment: That did what I wanted. That's a good point on the two variables! Thanks

Comment: Just to help others, you don't need to call `.sort` on `category`, you just want to return the value to sort on. In this case, the attribute is literally called `sort`. But if it was `name` you would just call `category.name`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `order` method to do the sorting at the database:

```
@categories = Extra.order(sort: :asc).group_by(&:category)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, I believe that only orders extras by sort as it is chained directly on Extra class. @deepak-mahakale worked in sorting the latter (Category). Thanks

Comment: I ended using both your suggestions as I have a sort in the extras also.

Comment: @DanielSousa: If the related tables can be large, then it could be more efficient to also do the `group by` operation in the database, using the [Active Record group method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group)

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and group_by together. You can even group by any other column in your Extra table. I am assuming category is a column inside the Extra table and name is also a column inside Extra table. but why are you naming it @categories? if you're dealing with Extra table?

```
def index
  @categories = Extra.all.map{|e| [e.name, e.category, e.id]}.group_by { |c| c[1] }
end
```

But you can also use this in your view as well, in your form_for with check_box_tag for checkboxes or radios or grouped_options_for_select